# Split the single column to 4 different columns in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just need need to split a single column of dataframe to 4 different columns. I tried few steps but didn't worked.

DATA1:

```
 Dump               
12525 2 153898 Winch
24798 1 147654 Gear
65116 4        Screw 
46456 1        Rowing
46563 5        Nut
```

Expected1:

```
 Item  Qty  Part_no  Description             
12525  2    153898   Winch
24798  1    147654   Gear
65116  4             Screw 
46456  1             Rowing
46563  5             Nut
```

DATA2:

```
 Dump               
12525 2 153898 Winch Gear
24798 1 147654 Gear nuts
65116 X        Screw bolts
46456 1        Rowing rings
46563 X        Nut
```

Expected2:

```
 Item  Qty  Part_no  Description             
12525  2    153898   Winch Gear
24798  1    147654   Gear nuts
65116  X             Screw bolts
46456  1             Rowing rings
46563  X             Nut
```

I tried the below code

```
data_df[['Item','Qty','Part_no','Description']] = data_df["Dump"].str.split(" ", 3, expand=True)

and got the output like 

 Item  Qty  Part_no  Description             
12525  2    153898   Winch
24798  1    147654   Gear
65116  4    Screw 
46456  1    Rowing
46563  5    Nut
```

Any suggestions, how can i fix this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
data_df[['Item','Qty','Part_no','Description']] = \
data_df['Dump'].str.extract(r'(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d*)\s*(\w+)')
```

Output:

```
                    Dump   Item Qty Part_no Description
0   12525 2 153898 Winch  12525   2  153898       Winch
1    24798 1 147654 Gear  24798   1  147654        Gear
2   65116 4        Screw  65116   4               Screw
3  46456 1        Rowing  46456   1              Rowing
4     46563 5        Nut  46563   5                 Nut
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. its really helpful. But When the description is like 2 words.. for ex: "Winch Gear", How can I fix that in the code?

Comment: Use `r'(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d*)\s*(.+)$')` as regex

Comment: I have few more issues and I have updated the question with Data2. Do you have any suggestions??

Comment: Use: `r'(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d*)\s*(.+)$')`. `\d` restricts the match to digits

Comment: It works. Thank you. But can you let me know what does 'S' do?? I know that \d restricts digits and \D restricts characters but not sure about \S

Comment: this means any non-space character, you should read a regex tutorial ;)

Comment: Thanks. But sometimes, the Part_no have space in between. for example: '153 89-8'. At that times, the code fails

Comment: @Pravin well, it's not necessarily possible to **guess** all the future possibilities, but I see you opened a new question ;)